# Merge two data tables by 2 IDs

Tags: r

I have an existing data table looking like this with various entries:

| record_id | event_name | lab_value_1 | lab_value_2 | lab_value_3 | lab_value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID 1 | t0 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| ID 2 | t1 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| ID 2 | t2 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | NA |

From another program I can get tables with individual data sets looking like this:

A) adding missing values to existing entries:

| record_id | event_name | lab_value_1 | lab_value_2 | lab_value_3 | lab_value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID 2 | t2 | NA | NA | NA | 0.5 |

B) adding new record_ids

| record_id | event_name | lab_value_1 | lab_value_2 | lab_value_3 | lab_value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID 3 | t0 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.5 |

C) Adding new time points to existing entrys

| record_id | event_name | lab_value_1 | lab_value_2 | lab_value_3 | lab_value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID 2 | t3 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.5 |

**IMPORTANT: The order of the columns can be different between the dataframes!**

So essentially, the new entry should be merged with the existing entries if record_id and event_name are identical. If not, they should get a new entry. I fiddled around with merge but couldn't get right results.

Any ideas, how to get it right?

Edit: Response to the first answer:

```
old_data
  record_id redcap_event_name lab_ldl lab_ggt lab_cpept lab_alat lab_asat lab_hba1c
1 ADI757106          t3_arm_1    0.12    0.51        NA       NA       NA        NA
2 ADI123456          t1_arm_1      NA      NA     0.133    0.155     47.3        NA


> new_data
  record_id redcap_event_name lab_ldl lab_hba1c
1 ADI123456          t1_arm_1       1         5

merge(old_data, new_data, by = c("record_id", "redcap_event_name"), all = TRUE, sort = TRUE)

  record_id redcap_event_name lab_ldl.x lab_ggt lab_cpept lab_alat lab_asat lab_hba1c.x lab_ldl.y lab_hba1c.y
1 ADI123456          t1_arm_1        NA      NA     0.133    0.155     47.3          NA         1           5
2 ADI757106          t3_arm_1      0.12    0.51        NA       NA       NA          NA        NA          NA
```

Exactly the same output for:

```
> merge(old_data, new data, by = c("record_id", "redcap_event_name"), all = TRUE, sort = TRUE)
```

So instead of merging lab_ldl and lab_hba1c into the existing columns, new ones get created.

Answer (score 2):

Solution involved [coalesce_join()](https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/) (see below):

```
coalesce_join(old_data, new_data, by = c("record_id", "event_name"))
```

And for multiple `new_data`s:

```
df_l <- list(old_data, new_data_1, new_data_2, new_data_3, ...)
purrr::reduce(df_l, ~ coalesce_join(.x, .y, by = c("record_id", "event_name")))
```

---

```
coalesce_join <- function(x, y, 
                          by = NULL, suffix = c(".x", ".y"), 
                          join = dplyr::full_join, ...) {
    joined <- join(x, y, by = by, suffix = suffix, ...)
    # names of desired output
    cols <- union(names(x), names(y))
    
    to_coalesce <- names(joined)[!names(joined) %in% cols]
    suffix_used <- suffix[ifelse(endsWith(to_coalesce, suffix[1]), 1, 2)]
    # remove suffixes and deduplicate
    to_coalesce <- unique(substr(
        to_coalesce, 
        1, 
        nchar(to_coalesce) - nchar(suffix_used)
    ))
    
    coalesced <- purrr::map_dfc(to_coalesce, ~dplyr::coalesce(
        joined[[paste0(.x, suffix[1])]], 
        joined[[paste0(.x, suffix[2])]]
    ))
    names(coalesced) <- to_coalesce
    
    dplyr::bind_cols(joined, coalesced)[cols]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works partly. However, it creates new columns named .x and .y.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some example data and your desired output?

Comment: Ah, I think you need [coalesce_join](https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/coalescing-joins/). The `data.table` solution is not general enough for your application. That is, you need something like `coalesce_join(old_data, new_data, by = c("record_id", "event_name"))`.

Comment: I think it's exactly what I need!
Gonna try it out more and let you know again. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have multiple `new_data`s, so you will need to do something like `purrr::reduce(list(old_data, new_data_1, new_data_2), ~ coalesce_join(.x, .y))`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm only passing one new_data at a time.
However, if you can help me with that: When I load a csv for the old data which only contains the header (as a template when using it the first time), I get: Error in `join()`:
! Can't join `x$record_id` with `y$record_id` due to incompatible types.
ℹ `x$record_id` is a <logical>.
ℹ `y$record_id` is a <character>.

So I guess, I'd need to change the "empty" row to character. How to do that?

Comment: Seems to be more general. Sometimes after importing the csv files with old_data the error occurs during coalesce:
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `dplyr::coalesce()`:
! Can't combine `..1` <double> and `..2` <character>.

How can I import all the entrys in the data field as character?

Comment: Sorry for the spam, I guess:
existing_data <- existing_data %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character))
did the trick!